# Why don't GCP, AWS or Azure support IGMP multicast/broadcast?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, multicast

It's well known that GCP/AWS/Azure do not support IGMP multicast or broadcast. Some state it's because of security concerns, but don't mention what those concerns are.

Is there a reason why these cloud providers do not support such long-standing, well-specified routing paradigms?

Comment: Each provider likely has their own reasons, and it is nearly impossible to know what that reason is unless the provider makes a statement on it, which they're unlikely to do.

Comment: @womble are you speculating this? Or is that a definitive answer? If there is a technical reason, there will be a definitive answer. This is not an unfocused or subjective question. Your assumption that it's an arbitrary reason is not a reason to close - the question is perfectly answerable. We can take this to Meta for a vote if you'd like... I don't appreciate questions being unilaterally judged in the first five minutes of it being asked. That's not how SE should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is for preventing multicast flood, if Cloud virtual network support IGMP multicast, one physical interface of switch or router could be receive ton of package from several multicast, it is same as multicast flood, their physical switches and routers will easily overload.